# Parsing XML Files with PowerShell

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell

To give an idea of how the XML code looks like that I am working with here.

```
<content>
<text id="new-users">
<Chinese>Nuevos usuarios</Chinese>
<English>New Users</English>
</text>
<text id="create-an-account">
<Chinese>Crear una Cuenta</Chinese>
<English>Create an Account</English>
</text>
```

I want to pull All of the English text between the < English > the test< /English >
and have it listed then add a comma to the end. 
to export it to excel.

I can't understand what powershell is doing I am kind of lost. I can get "text" to print out a lot of times and I looked in to printing out the get-contents then piping the contents with a sort to only print the English and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us what PowerShell script you've written so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are a couple of ways to get to the data. Here is the XPath way:

```
[xml]$x = Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.xml
$x.SelectNodes('//text/English') | Export-CSV C:\Path\To\Result.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

Comment: Isn't $x.SelectNodes("//English") enough?

Comment: Probably, I just tend to be more explicit out of habit.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
[xml] $xml = gc file.xml
$xml.content.text | select English | Export-CSV test.csv -notype
```

Comment: I think you probably meant this comment to be on my answer, but you are probably right that it would be sufficient.

Comment: @EBGreen - lol, sorry didn't even realize that I had commented on my own answer :)